# uncaught promise rejection: interface conversion: interface {} is int, not primitive.D

Tags: mongodb, realm

I'm trying out the MongoDB Realm functions, I have a simple function which makes an api call gets an array in response and stores it into a collection using the `bulkWrite` method.

```
exports = async function(arg) {
  const http = context.http;
  const db = context.services.get("mongodb-atlas").db("RealmCluster");
  
  let res = await http.get({ url: 'some url here'});
  let body = EJSON.parse(res.body.text());

  db.collection('assets').bulkWrite(body.assets);
};
```

But I'm getting this vague error and I've no clue whats going on:

```
error: 
uncaught promise rejection: interface conversion: interface {} is int, not primitive.D
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Well, referring to the documentation on [bulkWrite](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/mongodb/actions/collection.bulkWrite/#collection.bulkwrite--) may be revealing. Also, it's a good idea to also tag your question with your coding platform so coders familiar with that language will see it.

Answer (score 0):

I was using `bulkWrite` incorrectly, replaced it with `insertMany` and it worked!